# Stop myself from over-complicating applications

Tags: architecture, development-process

Recently I worked on a fairly large project involving C# and MVVM. This application had around 160 projects in the solutions each seprarated into their own layers. As I have been working on this application for almost a year, building it from scratch as part of a team, I am now coming off that project and onto smaller more trivial projects.

As I was beginning to develop a small in-house tool I found myself trying to mimic the larger applications structure and layering but in the end I just had a simple application with several DLLs which I know I wouldn't have done if I had not worked on that larger application before.

I am just wondering if there are any techniques I can utilise to stop myself from turning a "code-behind" style trivial application into a full blown MVVM application?

Or should I continue developing as I am and try to keep the unnecessary fluff out of the project?

Comment: its like listening to myself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am just wondering if there are any techniques I can utilise to stop myself from turning a "code-behind" style trivial application into a full blown MVVM application?

**Yes you can** easily stop yourself from over-engineering the application. Always look for the simple solutions over complex, and remember [**KISS and YAGNI**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/kiss-and-yagni.html) principles.

Comment: I think YAGNI really applies to what I am doing. I am trying to imagine the different scenarios this piece of software will be needing to be adapted to and thus creating a overly complex app. Thanks.